# (Completed) Should [answers] be a synonym of [responses]?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Should [answers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answers) be a synonym of [responses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/responses)?  The "answers" tag has no tag information, and has been misused to tag questions that are asking for answers (or corrections to answers) for practice exam questions. The "responses" tag has a description and is more likely in my opinion to be associated with questions about the grammar and phrasing of responses to questions.

I do not have enough reputation in [responses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/responses) to suggest the synonym - someone with at least a score of 5 or greater in the tag and 2500 reputation would need to suggest it.

Comment: Why don't those say: tagged questions?

Comment: @Lambie Why don't what say? I don't understand.

Comment: What the **** is the "response"? And why plural??

Comment: Collen when you click on those links, they say: questions tagged, as if they were saying: The questions tagged are A, B and C. Instead of using Tagged questions, adjectivally.

Comment: @Lambie That would be a question for Stack Exchange folks. We have no control over that. They chose “Questions (that have been) tagged (with) [tag name]. I assume because it was the least awkward way to include the name of the tag the questions were tagged with.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly it should be unless someone can come up with a different meaning for it, and give it as tag information.