# Weird behavior of [answers] tag when asking question

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

After [this meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5458/completed-should-answers-be-a-synonym-of-responses), the tags [responses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/responses) and [answers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answers) were [synonymized](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/responses/synonyms), and their behavior in most cases seems to reflect this. They remap, redirect, etc., but I noticed this earlier today when I was asking a question:

> [image]

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags have not been merged. If they were merged, and [answers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answers) merged in [responses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/responses), questions like [Yes/no answer on a specific statement](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/278265) would show [responses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/responses) as used tag.

The tags should have been first merged; then [answers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answers) should have been added as synonym of [responses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/responses). (Merging tags is an operation only moderators, Community Managers, or Stack Overflow developers can do. They can also merge two tags and create a synonym from the same page.)
A moderator can still merge those tags.